# jsQR unable to parse datamatrix

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

I am using jsQR in my angular 6 app; it's work fine with QRCODE.

But it's unable to parse datamatrix.

The docs can't report any configuration about this settings: any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.